# java.lang.RuntimeException: Field 'ANSWER' is not a java.lang.String

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I am accessing data from firestore, but it cant access the `Integer.valueOf(doc.getString("ANSWER"))`
because it gives me the exception of

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Field 'ANSWER' is not a java.lang.String

I don't know where is my mistake i m converting the  field ANSWER into number but its not access.

Here is my code of this method

```
private void getQuestionList() {

    questionList = new ArrayList<>();
    firestore.collection("QUIZ").document("CAT" + String.valueOf(category_ID))
            .collection("SET" + String.valueOf(setNo)).get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        QuerySnapshot questions = task.getResult();

                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc: questions){
                            questionList.add(new Question(doc.getString("QUESTION"),
                                    doc.getString("A"),
                                    doc.getString("B"),
                                    doc.getString("C"),
                                    doc.getString("D"),
                                    Integer.valueOf(doc.getString("ANSWER"))
                            ));
                        }

                        setQuestion();

                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(QuestionsActivity.this, Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    loadingDialog.cancel();
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a screenshot of a document that you're getting this error on.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo check out the image of my database structure where i wan to access "ANSWER" field which is in number

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen check out the picture of my database structure where i want to access "Answer" field which data type is number ...kindly help me

Comment: @HamzaMalik Have you tried Indiana's solution?

Comment: @HamzaMalik did my answer solve your issue? If so, be great to get a selected answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Your Answer pameter in Firestore contains a number and not a string. So the .getString function is wrong. Is there a .getInt or perhaps .getLong function that you can use instead?

```
doc.getString("A"),
doc.getString("B"),
doc.getString("C"),
doc.getString("D"),
Integer.valueOf(doc.getLong("ANSWER"))
```